# Using alias in ORDER BY clause in h2db

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, h2

I try to test my queries in h2db that I am using in MySQL, but I got an exception that my column "name" not found.

My query looks like this:

```
select t1.name as name, t1.code
from table1 t1
where t1.total > 50

union

select t2.name as name, t2.code
from table2 t2
where t2.total < 50

order by UPPER(name)
```

I've got exception

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "name" not found;

How can I run such queries in h2db?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try ordering by t1.name and does it make any difference?

Comment: Could you post the complete error message and stack trace? I couldn't reproduce the problem with a recent version of H2. The query above works for me. Maybe you are using an old version of H2, or you are using a different query?

Comment: Sorry.  I missed one function in order by clause. I am using "order by UPPER(name)"

Comment: I try to use "order by UPPER(t1.name)" and it's work but it's not what I need. I use 2 queries with union so I have to use alias in order by clause

Comment: If you are using `union`, then please post the complete query (including the `union`). There is one `order by` clause per `union`.

Comment: I have edited sql. Also I have added ALIAS_COLUMN_NAME=TRUE to url but it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your query works in MySQL, but fails in other databases, such as PostgreSQL, with this exception:

```
ERROR: invalid UNION/INTERSECT/EXCEPT ORDER BY clause
Detail: Only result column names can be used, not expressions or functions. 
0A000/0
```

For compatibility, use the following query instead:

```
select t1.name as name, upper(t1.name) uname, t1.code
from table1 t1
union
select t2.name as name, upper(t2.name) uname, t2.code
from table2 t2
order by uname
```